# Keycloak, sharing resources between clients

Tags: oauth-2.0, authorization, microservices, keycloak, openid-connect

We're developing an application with microservice-based architecture where users can be members of organizations, and within each organization, they may have resource-based access restrictions. An example can be a recruiter who's a member of several organizations on the platform; in organization *A* they may see the list of all job postings and interviewers while in organization *B* they can only see job-posting that they are directly allowed to see.

Structure wise this becomes something like this:
[image]

All this seems easy to do with Keycloak, we create confidential clients(one for each microservice) and enable resource management on them. However, there are quite some cases when different microservices (i.e., Keycloak clients) need to validate user's access scopes to the same resource. An example would be a setup where we have 2 microservices one for posting & managing job announcements the other for managing applications and interviews, so *job-manager* and *application-manager*. Now, when a new application is submitted, or an interviewer tries to access an application *application-manager* has to make sure that the user has access to the job posting(resource) configured in the *job-manager* Keycloak client. Which, I think, is not something Keycloak supports.

Scale wise, we're speaking about X00k users, 4-5 times that organization users connections, and tens of millions of resources. So to minimize the number of objects we're creating in Keycloak, we've decided to make use of attributes on resources in which we store JSON structures.

So, how one microservice, can verify a user's access to a resource manager by another microservice?

Comment: Have you managed to find the answer to your question ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to enable fine-grained authorization:
https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/#_resource_server_enable_authorization

This allows for resource based authorization. The resource does not have to necessarily be each resource you have, but an abstraction like an org_manager etc...

Alternatively you can take the json you already have and ask an OPA agent with a policy you defined.

https://www.openpolicyagent.org/